# Which is the kanji for "light"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, kanji

I know the kanjis 明 and 光, which both have (I guess) the idea of light.

Is there any difference between them? And what is the kanji for "normal" light, as the light of the sun or the light emitted by a bulb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

光 is the kanji for "light" (eg 光の速度 = speed of light, 光源 = source of light). Note that a light as a device is ライト, 明かり or 照明. The kanji 明 is more like "bright" (eg 明るい部屋 = bright room).